# Xamarin.Forms: How to develop an application with bluetooth connectivity in Xamarin.Forms crossplatform project?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms: I am new to Xamarin development envirorment. I need to develop a cross platform project (Android, Ios and windows) with bluetooth connectivity. Whether it is possible to develop in Xamarin.Forms crossplatform project else how can I achieve this through .Net technology. Because I have the knowledge in .Net technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 4 or 5 NuGet packages aimed to BLE and Xamarin.Forms.
Not to mention the examples here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27250/bluetooth-support-in-xamarin-forms
So yes, it is definitively possible (i'm doing this right now :D)